# jquery get neighbor html value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having following html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h5>Testing</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><span class='ent'>test</span></li>
        <li><span class='ent'>test</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h5>Testing123</h5>
    <ul>
        <li><span class='ent'>test</span></li>
        <li><span class='ent'>test</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a click function

```
$('.ent').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).html()); #This works fine
    alert($(this).find('h5').html()) #This is undefined
})
```

I can assume that this is referring current element but how can i get the neighbor element html.

Comment: You need to use a relative selector, `.find` looks **down** the tree, you need to look **up**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
alert($(this).closest('ul').prev('h5').html());
```

or

```
alert($(this).parent().prev('h5').html());
```

or

```
alert($(this).closest('.wrapper').find('h5').html());
```

---

problem with your code `.find()` looks down the tree your element `h5` is above so your need get the parent `element` with class `wrapper` than use `find` or get parent `ul` and get previous element using `.prev()`

---

Reference

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)